# cvHaarDetectObjects(): "Stack aound the variable 'seq_thread' was corrupted."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv

I have been looking in to writing my own implementation of Haar Cascaded face detection for some time now, and have begun with diving in to the OpenCV 2.0 implementation.

Right out of the box, running in debug mode, Visual Studio breaks on `cvhaar.cpp:1518`, informing me:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack aound the variable `seq_thread` was corrupted.

It seems odd to me that OpenCV ships with a simple array out-of-bounds problem. Running the release works without any problems, but I suspect that it is merely not performing the check and the array is exceeding the bounds.

Why am I receiving this error message? Is it a bug in OpenCV?

Comment: Could you state more clearly what your question is please? :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry; upon review there really wasn't any question at all. I also added the possible source of the problem.

Comment: I have not had much luck debugging OpenCV in VS2008.  I typically resort to building an install package and testing my application that way, or at the least making an .exe and dropping it in a folder with the necessary OpenCV .dll files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little debugging revealed the culprit, I believe. I "fixed" it, but this all still seems odd to me.

An array of size `CV_MAX_THREADS` is created on `cvhaar.cpp:868`:

```
CvSeq* seq_thread[CV_MAX_THREADS] = {0};
```

On line 918 it proceeds to specify `max_threads`:

```
max_threads = cvGetNumThreads();
```

In various places, `seq_thread` is looped using the following `for` statement:

```
for( i = 0; i < max_threads; i++ ) {
    CvSeq* s = seq_thread[i];
    // ...
}
```

However, `cxmisc.h:108` declares `CV_MAX_THREADS`:

```
#define CV_MAX_THREADS 1
```

Hence, the declaration of `seq_thread` must never be allowed to exceed size 1, yet `cvGetNumThreads()` returns 2 (I assume this reflects the number of cores in my machine).

I resolved the problem by adding the following simple little statement:

```
if (max_threads > CV_MAX_THREADS) max_threads = CV_MAX_THREADS;
```

Does any of this make sense?